# How to select max value from oracle sql table column and make a trigger using that value

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a trigger as follows

```
create or replace TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER
  BEFORE INSERT ON MY_TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.ID := max(ID)+100;
END;
```

Whenever I insert a new row into the table I want the new ID(a column in MY_TABLE) to be 100 more than the maximum value of ID already existing in the table. I cannot use max(ID) inside the trigger. Can someone tell what can be used instead of that to pick out the max value

Comment: Why do you want to generate `id` values this way?  This approach, for example, does not work in a multi-user system.  You'd get duplicate values which I assume you don't want.  You would normally use a sequence which is both vastly more efficient and produces correct results in multi-user systems.

Comment: max is an SQL function, you have to use it in a query